# Retrive value from a cell in one table to another cell in another table in Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, ms-office

I was wondering if there is some way to reference a value in one cell from one table to another cell in a different table using MS Word 2013...

In Excel you can simply indicate which cell you want to reference by using the equal sign and the cell we want, like: "=A3"

Sorry if this the wrong place to ask this kind of question but Stackoverflow is always my place to seek the answers to my questions :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

There are really two things you can do without too much effort, but they are both limited. I am assuming these are ordinary Word tables.

If you know the value is numeric, you can use an { = } field to reference it.

- Inside the same table, you can use { =A3 } to get the numeric value
  of A3.
- Outside the table, you must bookmark the table (I normally select the whole table and insert a bookmark - let's say it is "mytesttable". Then, ideally you would be able to use something like { =mytesttable:A3 } or some such. But unfortunately, you have to use a function (only AVERAGE, COUNT, MAX, MIN, PRODUCT and SUM can be used in this case). So you can use

  { =SUM(mytesttable A3:A3) }

(as usual, all the {  } have to be the special field code braces that you can insert in Widnows Word using ctrl-F9). Further, you have to update the values of most field types explicitly by selecting them and pressing F9.

Cell references are not the same as in Excel either. You can use An type referencing, but there are no relative references. If you want to sum a column you can use { =SUM(mytesttable A;A) } and the equivalent for rows. RnCn type referencing only works in some cases and the "R" and "C" are locale-dependent. I would also avoid using bookmarks that look like cell names when you have tables in a word document - start the bookmark name with 3 letters.

For non-numeric values, the best you can easily do is bookmark the value (let's call the bookmark "myvalue") then and use a { REF myvalue } or { myvalue } field to insert a copy of the value elsewhere.

The problem with this is that if the user extends the value outside the bookmark, the { REF } field will not pick up the whole value. If you try to work around that by bookmarking the cell, the { REF } field returns a copy of the whole cell (i.e. a one-cell table).

If you know that the values are numeric or valid dates, you can extract the value using a suitable picture switch, e.g.

for numbers...

```
{ myvalue \#0.00 }
```

and for dates...

```
{ myvalue \@DD-MM-YYYY }
```

I would avoid the first because it is better to use the approach I described above, and because you either have to know what the numbers look like (so that you can provide a suitable format) or you have to do an additional workaround.

For example, suppose A3 contains "1.2345"

Then { myvalue #0.00 } would be "1.23"

If you try to allow for any valid number of trailing digits using

```
{ myvalue \#0.0000000000000 }
```

(I forget exactly how many zeros you need) or

```
{ myvalue \#0.00########### }
```

then the field result will contain those trailing zeros or spaces. You can work around that using

```
{ ={ myvalue \#0.################ } }
```

Similarly for the dates. What you end up with is a date with the format you specified. You don't end up with a copy of the date as entered in the other table. As long as you know which format is required, you can provide the correct format, but it's quite a kludge.

Beyond that, you either have to think in terms of using a Word form, or using content controls and a certain amount of document protection.

Comment: Hi bibadia. First of all thanks a lot for this great explanation. I'm just facing a issue when trying to reference values from a different table. If I call the bookmark "test" and use it in the same table that contains the value that I'm referencing than the the code {=SUM(test B2:B2)} works but if I use it in other table, it gives me this error: !test Is Not In Table. Any suggestion?

Comment: How did you create the bookmark "test" ? I just wonder whether you have recreated it outside the table whos B2 cell you want to reference. I can only suggest that you reselect that table and recreate the "test" bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, word tables arn't that complex, if you want something like that i would strongly recommend you to actually use an external excel spreadsheet, if you're really desperate to get something like that inside your word document you can always take a print screen once you're done ;)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick reply. I just wanted to simplify the work to the person who will fill the tables since the same value repeats in multiple tables.

Comment: ahahahahha I wanted to make it work automatically but maybe there's no way :(